# SSIS: ole db source [55] error 0xC0202009.

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

We have a production SQL Server instance (Enterprise), on which all SSIS packages run fine. We've recently created a development server (on SQL Server development edition) and have run into the below error when trying to use an OLE DB connection in SSIS:

> [Execute SQL Task] Error: Failed to acquire connection "[SERVER NAME]". Connection may not be configured correctly or you may not have the right permissions on this connection.
>
> [Connection manager "[SERVER NAME]"] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
>   An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Unable to complete login process due to delay in opening server connection".

It might be worth noting that using an ADO NET Connection works fine. Also there are no problems when querying the database through SSMS.

Comment: Which version SQL Server/SSIS?

Comment: IS it a linked server?

Comment: Hi, it's SQL Server 2016. No, it's not a liked server

Comment: Try changing the connection time.  You should be able to configure that somewhere.  (It can be explicitly coded into the connection string if you are using a connection string.)

Comment: @BoCoKeith This solves the problem thanks. Turns out you need to change the connection managers timeout limit to something other than 0 then change it back to set the timeout to unlimited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the connection managers timeout limit to something other than 0 then changing it back to 0 to set the timeout to unlimited solved the issue.